# PHP-Admin, student LogIn

Tags: php, html

I want that when submit button is clicked, if admin has logged in the html page should redirect to admin.php page and a student has logged in, it should redirect to student.php page. There will be only 'one' id-password combination for admin(hardcoded), so I want to know if using if-else statement in a php script can I redirect to a new php script?
Is it possible to do this using a single SUBMIT button only?

```
     <?php
     if($_POST['username'] === 'admin' and $_POST['password'] === 'password'){
       go to admin.php;  //Admin login page
     }
    else{
    go to student.php; //Student has logged in => go to student login page
    }   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

you can do this for redirecting:

```
header('Location: /student.php');
```

Please note: you may not output anything before the header function else it do not work.

Or you can do this with javascript

```
<script>
    window.location = "student.php";
</script>
```

Or with a meta refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=student.php">
```

the 0 is the delay, when it should redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if($_POST['username'] === 'admin' && $_POST['password'] === 'password'){
     header('Location:admin.php');
 }
else if($_POST['username'] === 'student' && $_POST['password'] === 'password'){
    header('Location:student.php');
  }
else{
     header('Location:login.php');
  } 
}  
?>
```

Submit Button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do might be the following :

```
 <?php
   if($_POST['username'] === 'admin' and $_POST['password'] === 'password'){
     header('Location:admin.php');
   }
  else{
     header('Location:student.php');
  }   
?>
```

This will redirect the users to the page you want.

Also as Rocky said you must not have any output before your header otherwhile you'll get the error : Header already sent

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

If the value is hardcoded as you say, then this code should work:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['username'] === 'admin' && $_POST['password'] === 'password'){
   header("Location: admin.php");  //Admin login page
 }
else{
header("Location: student.php"); //Student has logged in => go to student login page
}   
?>
```

Hardcoding values isn't a good option in most cases but this code is what will do it.

You can even use the following meta refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=student.php">
```

There are other ways to do it as well but I don't think you need them. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I know, I'm ask to do this in the mini-project statement. However only the admin is hard-coded, I'll be writing a script for student id-password combination check.